# Does 13.04 have power/suspend issues with Sandy Bridge?

Tags: kernel, 13.04, sandy-bridge

I have an i5 Sandy Bridge Laptop and currenty use 12.10 with Linux 3.5. I heard that the Kernel 3.6 has some issues with Sandy Bridge, i. e. does not wake up from suspend, or run on 100 % CPU load after suspend.

Is the 3.8 Kernel a problem with Sandy Bridge CPUs?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no. My Thinkpad X220 with i5 sandy bridge use a lot of energy with kernel 3.8 and it`s really hot on CPU. But most of time, the temperature beetween 70. (not always actually. playing fullHD gives me 90 celcium, so I need to use an external cooler) This is better then on HOT-HOT-HOT 3.6, but still, it is highly recommended to use 12.04 LTS release with this knd of CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Sandy Bridge i5 and i7 processors in the X220 have a known, unresolved issue involving suspend, causing it to run at 100% after suspend. Here's the bug report:

i915 doesn't reach RC6 state after s2ram - Thinkpad T420, X220
 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48791